# How to write test-case for Directive with in Directive using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I wrote a test for my directive using jasmine testcase framework with karma testcase runner.
In my project ,I am already having one directive called

```
<parent-directive></parent-directive>
```

and i tried to include that parent directive into another one called

`<child-directive></child-directive>.`

Parent directive elements are converted as components called **SampleComponents** and included in the child directive

**Sample.js**

```
'use strict'

angular.module('Sample')
  .directive('SampleHeader', SampleHeader)

function SampleHeader () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'header/header.html',
    scope: {},
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.logoutHeader = function () {
        console.log('Logout call back')
        require('electron').remote.app.quit()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**SampleSpec.js**

```
describe('SampleHeader', function () {
    var $compile, $rootScope, elements, scope, controller


    beforeEach(module('Sample'))
    beforeEach(module('SampleComponenets'))
    beforeEach(module('ngAnimate'))
    beforeEach(module('ngRoute'))
    beforeEach(module('ngMaterial'))
    beforeEach(module('ngCookies'))
    beforeEach(module('datatables'))


    beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$q_,_$controller_) {

        deferred = _$q_.defer()
        $compile = _$compile_
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_
        controller = _$controller_
        scope = $rootScope.$new()

        elements = angular.element('<sample-header></sample-header>')
        $compile(elements)($rootScope.$new())
        $rootScope.$digest()
        controller = elements.controller('SampleHeader')
        scope = elements.isolateScope() || elements.scope()
        scope.$digest()

    }))

    it('should check logoutHeader is called', function () {scope.logoutHeader()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**restrict: 'A' ->** it seems you created a attribute directive so you should compile the directive as a attribute ***(like, `elements = angular.element('<div sample-header></div>')`)***.

```
describe('SampleHeader', function () {
    var $compile, $rootScope, elements, scope, controller


    beforeEach(module('Sample'))
    beforeEach(module('SampleComponenets'))
    beforeEach(module('ngAnimate'))
    beforeEach(module('ngRoute'))
    beforeEach(module('ngMaterial'))
    beforeEach(module('ngCookies'))
    beforeEach(module('datatables'))


    beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$q_,_$controller_) {

        deferred = _$q_.defer()
        $compile = _$compile_
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_
        controller = _$controller_
        scope = $rootScope.$new()

        elements = angular.element('<div sample-header></div>')
        $compile(elements)($rootScope.$new())
        $rootScope.$digest()
        controller = elements.controller('SampleHeader')
        scope = elements.isolateScope() || elements.scope()
        scope.$digest()

    }))

    it('should check logoutHeader is called', function () {scope.logoutHeader()
    })
})
```

Comment: suppose  if in my directive is isolated scope and i am using '=' , '@' in my scope of directive for communication purpose so in that below line will be same
elements = angular.element('<div sample-header></div>')
or do i need to make any changes?